# PostgreSQL creating foreign key to all rows of another Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I am working on creation of a PostgreSQL Database.
I have 2 tables - Users and Projects

- table `Users` consist of: Id, Username, Password, and Project_ID (not sure if it's needed)

  - **Primary key** - Id
  - **Foreign Key** - Project_id as ID in **Projects** Table
- table `Project`: Id, Name, Status, Deadline

How can I (if I can) implement a relation one-to-many in this case?

So if I make a JOIN query to show me **User** with certain **ID** and all his linked **Projects**?

Or It would be easier to create a **User_ID** foreign key in the **Project** table relating to **Users** table ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks like you have a many-to-many relationship, where each user may participate multiple projects, and each project may involve multiple users. If so, then you need a third table in your design to represent that relationship - this is called a bridge table, or a junction table.

Sample DDL:

```
create table users (
    id int primary key,
    username text
);

create table projects (
    id int primary key,
    name text,
    status text,
    deadline date
);

create table user_projects (
    id int primary key,
    user_id int references users(id),
    project_id int references projects(id),
    unique (user_id, project_id)
);
```

Now say you want to list all users users, and all the projects they participate:

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u
inner join user_projects up on up.user_id = u.id
inner join projects p on p.id = up.project_id
order by u.id, p.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably didn't express myself correctly, that I want only to show the User with all his Projects, but not vice versa. Anyway I got the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

If your users are just project members, a single project may consist of multiple users and a user may be member in multiple projects. In that case @GMB provided the right answer.

But the correct answer depends also on your business: if every project has exactly one manager you can define a manager_id in project and this way every project is linked to 1 manager and a manager (=user) can be manager of multiple projects.

In the `user_project` you can also specify the role of the user within the project (assuming a user has only one role within a project).

Comment: Thanks, I really understood that didn't specify in particular what I want to have. I want to have User with all his projects, had to ask my self first what I want =D